# Adding nonce to <script> tag

Tags: php, wordpress, nonce

I'm wondering how to add nonce to my all `<script>` tags on page based on WordPress. For example please find some code below:

```
$my_nonce = wp_create_nonce('nonce-'.rand());
$nonces = "Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self nonce-".$my_nonce."'";
header( "{$nonces}");

wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'my_loadmore_params', array(
'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php',
'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), 
'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
         'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
) );`
```

And I want to have something like this:

```
<script nonce="nonce-value">...</script>
```

Where **nonce-value** is random.

This only one of places where I need this, is there any idea how to add it globally to `<script>` tag?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This isn't the normal way nonces are used in wordpress. There might be an answer to "how do you add a nonce to script tags globally?" But I don't think that's what you really want. Globally in what sense? ALL script tags? Huh?

Comment: why do you want to add the nonce to script tag? You can set id for it.

Comment: I assume this is for content security policy purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but Wordpress does provide a [script_loader_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) filter which allows you to modify the generated script tags from enqueued scripts.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script', 10, 3 );

function add_nonce_to_script( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    global $my_nonce;
    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '" nonce="' . esc_attr( $my_nonce ) . '"></script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I setup a function in functions.php to generate a the nonce using the built wordpress function.

```
add_action( 'run_custom_nonce_value', 'custom_nonce_value' );
function custom_nonce_value () {

    $created_nonce = wp_create_nonce();
    define( 'NONCE_RANDVALUE', $created_nonce ); 

}
```

Then I setup this filter to add the nonce value to all of the scripts

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script', 10, 3 );
function add_nonce_to_script( $tag, $handle, $source ) {

    custom_nonce_value();
    $val_nonce = NONCE_RANDVALUE;

    $search = "type='text/javascript'";
    $replace = "type='text/javascript' nonce='".$val_nonce."' ";
    $subject = $tag;

    $output = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
    return $output;
}
```

This solution will add the nonce to all correctly registered scripts.

Comment: Hey noob here, trying to implement CSP in WP. COuld you please further help me also... 2 questions:

how do I actually add it to header? I mean the Nonce should be in the headers as well as script tags... How to add it...

2nd does your code to add nonce to scripts work with inline JS too?

Comment: Also, I read that the nonces need to be base64 else they don't work... I am not even sure of what exactly does base64 mean, but does it comply with it?

Comment: You can edit header.php file to add the CSP there with the rules you want.  It does not add the nonce to scripts that are not loaded properly.  So, if a developer of a plugin just drops a script tag in the code that they wrote, this will not work.  It won't process those script tag.  They have to be registered and loaded via wordpress functions.

Comment: If you use wp_create_nonce() function, it will be in the proper format for you to use.

Comment: Hey there, I didn't hope to recieve a reply on 2 year old answer. Thanks for replying. I was desperate to have CSP so i posted question on WPSE, and turns out `wp_create_nonce()` is NOT right. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/395453/reliable-way-to-add-nonce-to-http-header-in-wordpress  and turns out the nonce generated lives for 24hrs. I tested it myself, the ideal behavior for CSP requires a new nonce on each page load/refresh

Comment: well now you have me curious. I think when i refresh the page, the nonce value changes. But, what you are saying is that the nonce is still alive. I'll need to test to make sure though.  If I generate a nonce on every page load, I'm wondering if that will take up alot of memory if i have alot of traffic to my website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
add_filter('script_loader_src','add_nonce_to_script',10,2);
function add_nonce_to_script($src, $handle){
   $my_nonce = wp_create_nonce('nonce-'.rand());
   return $src.' nonce= '.$my_nonce;
}
```

Hope this will helps you.
For more example,

[Adding Additional Attributes in Script Tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110929/adding-additional-attributes-in-script-tag-for-3rd-party-js)

Comment: This wouldn't pass the CSP since it's generating a new nonce every single call.

Comment: you used the rand() function. So, it will always pick a new random number for each in your nonce attribute.